# Get ParameterizedType from reified generic type for Moshi type adapter

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, moshi, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

The given assertion will fail due to the error

> Failed to find the generated JsonAdapter constructor for class GenericType

How do I get the proper type from the reified type `T` for `Moshi`?

The `GenericType` type is annotated with `@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)` using the *Kotlin* codegen for *Moshi* using only `Moshi.Builder().build()`.

I could generate `ParameterizedType` manually with

```
Types.newParameterizedType(GenericType::class.java, String::class.java)
```

where `GenericType::class.java` is given with `T:class.java`. But I don’t know how to get the `String` type parameter to generify the approach.

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> adapter() =
    moshi.adapter<T>(type<T>())

inline fun <reified T : Any> type() =
    T::class.java

assert(adapter<GenericType<String>>() != null)
```

**Note** that the adapter is available for any `GenericType<T>`, just not for the actual class `GenericType::class.java` without generic information.

So the following `genericType` would find an adapter as long as I know about `G`:

```
inline fun <reified G : Any> genericType() =
    newParameterizedType(GenericType::class.java, G::class.java)
```

This `G` is what I'm looking to find in `type()`, as `T::class.java`
 is just `GenericType::class.java` there.

Comment: What is the actual code that causes the crash? Could you please add it?

Comment: It's an issue in `adapter<GenericType<String>>()` with a basic _Moshi_ configuration with  `@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)` and _Kotlin_ codegen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin now provides an experimental [`typeOf<T>()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/type-of.html) function to return the `KType` of the reified type `T`. So the required code is as simple as:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> type() = typeOf<T>()
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm achieving my goal for now with a custom `TypeToken` approach similar to *Gson*

```
abstract class TypeToken<T>

inline fun <reified T : Any> type() = object : TypeToken<T>() {}::class
      .java
      .genericSuperclass
      .let { it as ParameterizedType }
      .actualTypeArguments
      .first()
```

But I'm still hoping to find an approach to get the the `ParameterizedType` from `T` directly.